# Electrical 'input' connector?

Tags: electrical

So, this is maybe a goofy thought. Here's the situation:

Putting the final finishing touches to our propane fireplace insert. The insert has an outlet built-in for a circulating fan if in the future that is desired. This is hardwired and should be connected to a junction box. I have no immediate need for this, so may just remove it, but I also thought that it'd be nice to future proof it for the next owner.

The catch is that there is no easy way to get the electrical to a junction box short of drilling through thick brick. However, I am running a switch from the fireplace to the side of the fireplace surround (which is wood) so I got to thinking...

Is there such thing as an 'electrical input' connector. The idea being one could run a cord from the outlet on the wall next to the fireplace to this 'input connector' on the side of the fireplace which in turn would power the outlet built in.

My guess is: **of course not, this is a crazy product idea that would likely lead to deaths.** But it never hurts to ask, right?

(PS, the back up idea is to just run it to a junction box on the side of the fireplace, and put a cover on it. If in the future anyone really wants to use it, they can take it from there and figure out how to get that to a powered junction box elsewhere. 
)

Comment: You'd in essence be turning your fireplace into a cord connected device, which is likely not a good idea. If used, the cord would be in place of fixed wiring, which is not allowed under NEC (400.8 (1)).

Comment: Well, not so much the fireplace. The fan. And most fans *are* cord connected devices...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sort of thing you are looking for exists; you can find them under the name **inlet** (opposite of outlet). The most commonly seen type is the [C14 socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIEC60320_C14.jpg) used on computer power supplies, but ones compatible with regular AC extension cords are also available.

(I'm not able to tell you whether using one in this application would be safe or code-compliant, so this doesn't fully address your question, but I hope knowing what it's called will help.)

Comment: I never thought of that! Good suggestion. Anyone know if they are applicable to household wiring?